# Workaround to Auto Commit Of DDL Statements Before Execution

Tags: oracle

I am keeping two passwords (actually the same password as far as website human user knows,but hashed and salted using two different algorithms and salts) for my website. One is place in WebUsers table and that is where password is verified when users login at website. The other is password of an oracle user, each website user corresponds to an oracle user.

When making change password procedure, I have to change password in WebUsers table as well as in oracle, in a transaction. The problem is, the DDL statement [alter user ...] commit before performing any action. If [alter user ...] fail and in the exception handling code I rollback the transaction, the changes in the WebUsers table are not rollbacked. Is there some work around?

Comment: Can't you just store the old hash value in a variable and update your WebUsers table again with the old value if the DDL fails?

Comment: Why are you saving the password in Oracle and also in a table? Is there a reason why your authentication cannot be combined, thus eliminating the problem entirely?

Answer (score 0):

There is just no way to have a DML and DDL in one atomic transaction under Oracle.

In Oracle a a DDL will always explicitly result in a commit before running the DDL.

Typically in these sort of scenarios, you should execute the step that's most likely to fail first, i.e. in your case the DDL 'Alter User'.

And then run your DML , only if the DDL succeeds , but then again, there is this issue of the DML failing, and then not being able to rollback the DDL, at which point you'll simply have to run another DDL to revert the changes made by the first DDL.

The idea is that the second step is far more likely to fail than the first step.

This pattern is also used, where you've to deal with say something like JMS + JDBC , and you can't use a JTA transaction to wrap the JMS + JDBC activities in a single transcation.